# ExtJs change anchor property dynamically

Tags: extjs

Have a question about changing anchor property dynamically...
I have some FormPanel, which contains one textfield, one panel and one textarea
for textarea I set "anchor : 100% -somevalue". Panel is added dynamically(when needed), so I want to change anchor property for textarea depending on whether Panel is added.

Comment: did you try to panel.doLayout()?

Answer (score 1):

Use `doLayout()`. Example:

```
var p = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    layout: 'anchor',

    items:[{
        title:'Item 1',
        html:'100% 20%',
        anchor:'100% 20%'
    },{
        title:'Item 2',
        html:'50% 30%',
        anchor:'50% 30%'
    },{
        title:'Item 3',
        html:'-100 50%',
        anchor:'-100 50%'
    }]
});

setTimeout(function(){
    p.items.items[0].anchor = '89% 20%';
    p.doLayout();
}, 2000);
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/uN2w9/1/